# Jest is trying to use babel in the part which should not be applied

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, koa

I created a project with koa and vue.

Webpack is used to build the index.js used in the front-end, while the backend part (koa) is running by node directly (with ES6 module).

I want to use Jest to write some unit tests to test the backend part of this app.

When running a test like this:

```
import server from '../../index.js';
import request from 'supertest';

test('adds 1 + 2 to equal 3', () => {
  expect(sum(1, 2)).toBe(3);
});
```

, Jest reports

```
$ node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js 
 FAIL  test/backend/router.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /home/edison/Coding/short-url/common/logger.js: Missing class properties transform.
      20 |   }
      21 |
    > 22 |   debug = (...args) => {
         |   ^
      23 |     if (!this.verbose) return;
      24 |
      25 |     args = this.appendTag(args);

      at File.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/transformation/file/file.js:240:12)
      at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/index.js:138:21)
      at pushBody (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/transformClass.js:141:20)
      at buildBody (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/transformClass.js:115:5)
      at classTransformer (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/transformClass.js:551:5)
      at transformClass (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/transformClass.js:587:10)
      at PluginPass.ClassExpression (node_modules/@babel/plugin-transform-classes/lib/index.js:69:54)
      at newFn (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/visitors.js:175:21)
      at NodePath._call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:55:20)
      at NodePath.call (node_modules/@babel/traverse/lib/path/context.js:42:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.694 s
Ran all test suites.
```

This project can run by `node index.js` without any errors and warnings.

How could I use Jest without invoking babel and webpack things?

For more information, here is the GitHub repository of this project: https://github.com/edisonhello/shorturl

Comment: Jest doesn't use Webpack. Jest uses Babel any way at least for hoisting, it should be configured properly or at least not configured at all to use default config. You didn't provide Babel and Jest configs in the question. It should be understandable without navigating to offsite link. In your case it's `"presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "vue"`. What does Vue do there?

Comment: @EstusFlask I built this project my referencing this tutorial: https://devs.tw/post/60 (It's Chinese, btw), and I just copied the setting in his `package.json`.

Comment: It's a mistake to keep both frontend and backend in the same project, you made your experience with Jest unnecessarily complicated. They are different things that have different deps and run in different envs. The only thing that unifies them is that Vue's dist should end up in Koa's public. You need to keep 2 configs in `jest.config-*.js` files and `babel.config-*.js` . Remove Jest and Babel entries from package.json as they are global. Custom Babel config can be specified like https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3845#issuecomment-582511237. Jest config can be specified as CLI argument